# Meteor detecting existence of field in collection

Tags: javascript, meteor, collections, ternary-operator

Pseudo code below.  My result collection of products has an optional subarray of images. What I'm trying to do is check if images exists for a product before trying to access an image.href to use as an image source.  In the case where images does NOT exist it breaks every time.  Alternately I've tried typeof 'undefined' and that didn't work either.

```
       if (this.products) {
            //return "<i class='fa fa-gift'></i>"
            console.log("has products");
            if (this.products[0].images) {  <--- breaks
                console.log("item 0 has images");
            }
            if (this.products.images) {  <--- breaks
                console.log("has images");
            }
        } else {
            console.log("don't have products");
        }
```

EDIT / UPDATE

Ultimately I think Patrick Lewis supplied the best answer for this - using a hybrid ternary operator.  Goes like:

myVar = object && object.name || "foo"

above would assign myVar the name value if the object exists and it has a name, or... it will assign static "foo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `this.products` is an empty array. Try:

```js
if (this.products && this.products.length) {
    var images = this.products[0].images;

    if (images && images.length) {
        console.log("item 0 has images");
    } else {
        console.log("item 0 does not have images");
    }
} else {
    console.log("don't have products");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast feedback, unfortunately neither of these worked for me.  These are two nested arrays.  When there is values, this is the assignment statement:  this.products[0].images[0].href.   The test below fails when checking images.  Frustrating!

Comment: Okay - gotcha - this is basically exactly what I landed on.

Answer (score 0):

this.products is your collection or the result of a query like MyColl.find() ?

if this is the result of a query you could do this :

```
if (typeof this.products == "object") {
  if (typeof this.products.images == "object") { // if images is a property of products and images is an array
// od what you want here
  }
}
```